# como resolver Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.ManyToOne co.mz.cth.model.Owner]

Tags: spring-boot

Saudações
Estou fazendo uma aplicação em springboot+thymeleaf (ainda sou novato nisto), tenho o seguinte caso: 
Existem dois objetos relacionados Owner e Car
No form. de registo do Car, contêm uma combobox que possui uma lista dinâmica de Owner(s)
ao dar o clique para fazer o save encontro-me com o seguinte erro:
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.ManyToOne co.mz.cth.model.Owner] for value '4'; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Provided id of the wrong type for class co.mz.cth.model.Owner. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class co.mz.cth.model.Owner. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String]]

abaixo os screenshot(s):
class  Car[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

class Owner 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Controller do Car

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

formulário do registo do Car 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

[Resolvido]  devia alterar o name do select para um outro qualquer por exemplo: id_owner desde que seja diferente dos atributos da classe e objeto, e na relacao dos objetos o owner devia estar mapeado deste modo: @OnetoMany(mappedBy="nomeDaClasseMinusculo")